# CSS drupal search api float elements

Tags: html, css, drupal

I have just implemented search api module and it works. I replaced the core search block with the block for the search api module.
With firefox I saw that the code after the two elements, the search element and the textfield (where you can write the words to search) is the folowing:

```html
<div id="edit-search-api-views-fulltext-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-filter-search_api_views_fulltext">
<div class="views-widget">
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-search-api-views-fulltext">
<input id="edit-search-api-views-fulltext" class="form-text" type="text" maxlength="128" size="30" value="" name="search_api_views_fulltext">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="views-exposed-widget views-submit-button">
<input id="edit-submit-searchadvanced" class="form-submit" type="submit" value="Zoeken" name="">
</div>
```

In my global.css I managed to set the elements at the left site. Now that they are at the right site, I want them to stand side by side and not among each other. I can speak to the elements seperatly, but setting them side by side is to difficult. I have read about float, display; inline, clear, ... 
Here is my code:

```css
/*float right and textbox and searchbutton disapear at the right side, I gave also a width of 240 px  */
#views-exposed-form-searchadvanced-page{
 float:right;
 width: 500px; 
}
/*the element edit-search-api-views-fulltext, is the textfield and has a blue color  */
#edit-search-api-views-fulltext{
background:blue;
}
/*the element edit-submit-searchadvanced, is the searchbutton and has a green color  */
#edit-submit-searchadvanced{
background:green;
```

I hope someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understood your question correctly, however I think you want to display the searchbox and button next to each other.

To achieve that the wrapper div (`#views-exposed-form-searchadvanced-page`) should be floated to the right (which you already did) and the searchbox and the button to the left.

```
/*the element edit-search-api-views-fulltext, is the textfield and has a blue color  */
#edit-search-api-views-fulltext {
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}
/*the element edit-submit-searchadvanced, is the searchbutton and has a green color  */
#edit-submit-searchadvanced {
  background: green;
  float: left;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MF82/uq0eLxm7/) for the complete, working example.

Comment: You did understood my question and thanks for your answer but I tried it out and it didn't work. Have to say that the wrapper is not the first in the hyrarchie. The float:right is on views-exposed-form-searchadvanced-page.

Comment: We have: 1 views-exposed-form-searchadvanced-page then 2 edit-search-api-views-fulltext-wrapper then 3 edit-search-api-views-fulltext. Then the divs ends and the button falls at the same level as the 2 and this one is called edit-submit-searchadvanced. Hope to see another idea of you. Tried in the mean time all possible variations...

Comment: Did you take a look at the fiddle? The ```float:right``` is there on views-exposed-form-searchadvanced-page. I will clarify my answer a bit. If it doesn't work, then it would be best that you provide a JSFiddle, since the code samples you provide in your question do not match the description you gave in the comment above. That way I can be more precise in my updated answer.

Comment: Your fiddle seems correct. I only forgot this code:

Comment: <div class="content clearfix">
<form id="views-exposed-form-searchadvanced-page" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get" action="/Sitran/?q=nl/searchadvanced">
<div>
<input type="hidden" value="searchadvanced" name="q">
<div class="views-exposed-form">
<div class="views-exposed-widgets clearfix">
<div id="edit-search-api-views-fulltext-wrapper"

Comment: First things first: I really want to help you. However it's hard for me to exactly figure out what exactly is going on in your application without a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) or perhaps the URL of the site where I can see more code and it's context. At the moment you're giving me parts of the code. Please provide a fiddle with the complete, relevant part of the code or the URL of the site you're working on.

Comment: My site turns local. I have set up [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zm4rvef/2/) _italic_ **bold** `code` and it gave the same result as you had. I see in firebug on mouse over the <div class="views-exposed-widget views-submit-button"> that it is the dubbel of the button hight. Is there a way to reduce this?  This is the class who is just before the botton. I think this might be the cause…

Comment: Your solution was the right solution for bringing the elements next to each other.  Thank you so much for the help!
In the meantime I found out that a margin-top causes the problem. I couldn’t see this because it is a setting that comes with the views module. Setting the top-margin:0em;  for the button has helped me putting it higher and so it came next to the other element. So case closed!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear that. If you feel that my answer helped you, please accept my answer. Accepted answers are an indication for other users of this site to which answers are useful.